# moving rows to another table and also inserting additional values

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently moving rows from "mycart" table to "itemorders" table.

```
$query = "INSERT into orders   
(email,address,postalcode,contactNo,orderdate,status) values
('".$email."','".$address."','".$postalcode."','".$contactNo."','".$orderdate."','".$status."');";   

$query .= "INSERT into itemorders (itemID,itemName,itemSize,itemPrice,quantity) SELECT itemID,itemName,itemSize,itemPrice,quantity FROM mycart WHERE email='".$email."' ";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn,$query);
$ordersID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Currently, i have an additional field called ordersID in "itemorders" table, the first query also Auto increments a ordersID. I want to insert the $ordersID value that i have used in the first query into the second query. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function in MySQL. It gets the last auto-increment ID, just as `mysqli_insert_id()` does.

```
$query .= "INSERT into itemorders (itemID,itemName,itemSize,itemPrice,quantity,orderSID) 
    SELECT itemID,itemName,itemSize,itemPrice,quantity, LAST_INSERT_ID()
    FROM mycart 
    WHERE email='".$email."' ";
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, one extra question. Do i just do another delete query if i want to delete the rows that i moved?

Comment: Yeah, there's no way to delete them automatically in the same query.